# Trying to change CSS of elements of a Loop in Laravel

Tags: css, laravel

**Question**

Hi, I am trying to print the first two categories images with col-xl-6, and the remaining categories images with col-xl-4. The size of the first two images is different from the last three. Please let me know how it will work. If you can share code it'll be awesome! Thanks.

**Blade-File**

```
@foreach ($categories as $cat)
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6  column">
                <a href='/products/{{$cat->id}}'>
                    {{-- style="height: 460px; width:345px; --}}
                    <div class="img">
                        <img class="cat-img mx-2" id="cat-img" src="/uploads/categories/{{$cat->image_url}}" />
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="title text-center">
                    <h2>{{$cat->title}}</h2>
                    <a href='products/{{$cat->id}}'>Shop Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `$loop` variable available that you can check if the index of current item with.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable

```
@if ($loop->index === 0 || $loop->index === 1)
// do stuff
@endif
```

Comment: so `$loop->index < 2`